# Displaying a database in PDF using iText in Android Studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite, pdf, itext

I have a function that creates a `PDF` file that displays a database (`SQLite`). When I try to open the file, it says: File read error. **File type is unsupportted or the file is corrupted.**

I don't have any errors in my logcat. I am using [iTextg 5.5.3.jar](http://repo.itextsupport.com//releases/com/itextpdf/itextg/5.5.3/) that I added using Sync Project with Gradle Files button of Android Studio.

What am I doing wrong? Please help me.

This is the PDF Create Function:

```js
else if (id == R.id.PDFCreate)
        {
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM '" + reciever +"' ",null);
            Cursor title = db.rawQuery("SELECT '" + reciever +"' FROM MasterClasslist", null);

            title.moveToFirst();
            //String filename = title.getString(title.getColumnIndex("Name"));
            String filename = "ClassManager.pdf";

            Document document = new Document();

            document.open();
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Class Manager Grades");

            if (!root.exists())
            {
                root.mkdirs();
            }

            File gpxfile = new File(root, filename);
            try
            {
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(gpxfile));
            }
            catch (DocumentException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph();
            p3.add("Class Manager");
            try
            {
                document.add(p3);
            }
            catch (DocumentException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(6);

            table.addCell("First Name");
            table.addCell("Last Name");
            table.addCell("Prelim Grade");
            table.addCell("Midterm Grade");
            table.addCell("Final Grade");
            table.addCell("Semestral Grade");

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int count = cursor.getCount();

            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            {
                table.addCell(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("FirstName")));
                table.addCell(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("LastName")));
                table.addCell(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("pGrade")));
                table.addCell(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mGrade")));
                table.addCell(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fGrade")));
                table.addCell(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("semGrade")));

                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            try
            {
                document.add(table);
            }
            catch (DocumentException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            document.addCreationDate();

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PDF Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();


        }
```

This warning shows up in the logcat:

```
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440): com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(PdfDocument.java:809)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at com.itextpdf.text.Document.add(Document.java:278)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at test.com.classmanagertest.ClassViewStudents.onOptionsItemSelected(ClassViewStudents.java:628)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2673)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1015)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:177)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1158)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2949)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3683)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.flushLines(PdfDocument.java:1344)
02-25 14:10:04.903: W/System.err(11440):    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(PdfDocument.java:748)
02-25 14:10:04.913: W/System.err(11440):    ... 21 more
```

Comment: check your ClassManager.pdf file. is it created in your SD card?

Comment: Yes, it is created. But cannot be opened.

Comment: *"cannot be opened"* even with application that support pdf reader?

Comment: Yeah I tried using apps like ubreader, think office and google drive readers. I even copied it to a pc and opening it using Adobe reader or chrome but still doesn't open.

Comment: then its your itext configuration. just remove all of your try/catch and make the error occurs in logcat

Comment: Android Studio doesn't allow me to run the app without try catch in the pdfwriter.getinstance and document.add

Comment: yes let it be. but make it catch all error using Exception e. and log it using `Log.e(TAG,e.getlocalizedmess);`

Comment: I don't see you closing the **document**...

Comment: @mkl : if i document.close() at the end of the function, i get a Runtime Exception saying the document is closed.

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira : i tried this Log.e(TAG,e.getLocalizedMessage()); but 'TAG' cannot be resolved as a symbol.

Comment: just use anything like "Erorr on me"

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira : Where does Log.e display? In the Logcat when there is an error?

Comment: your logcat.........

Comment: There is a warning though

Comment: Ah, not only do you not close the document, you also open it before attaching a PdfWriter instance. First you have to create a document, then attach it to a writer, then open it, then add content, then close it.

Comment: @mkl : what code should I write and where to insert it? (I'm new to Android programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You open the `document` before attaching a `PdfWriter` to it. Thus, the `PdfWriter` is not informed about the `document` being opened.
2. You don't close the `document` in the end. Thus, the PDF output remains unfinished.

The *iText in Action* example [HelloWorld](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=12) shows the correct order:

```
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
    // step 5
    document.close();
```